# CADisplayLink can't stop after invalidated

Tags: ios, cadisplaylink

I have two `UIButton`, the first button will trigger the CustomeView's `- beginAnimation` and the other one will trigger the `- endAnimation`. when I rapidly press these two button in turn, like `begin -> end -> begin -> end -> begin -> end`, I found that the `CADisplayLink` can't stop. What's more, the `- rotate`'s fire rate is more than 60fps, became `60 -> 120 -> 180`, just like there are more than one `CADisplaylink` in my main RunLoop, so is there anyway to fix it? And I need to keep the `CADisplaylink` running before the view's alpha come to zero, so I put the `[self.displayLink invalidate];` in the completion block, maybe this will cause this problem？

```
@interface CustomeView : UIView
@end

@implementation CustomeView

- (void)beginAnimation // triggered by a UIButton
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{ self.alpha = 1.0; }];
    self.displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(rotate)];
    [self.displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
}

- (void)endAnimation // triggered by another UIButton
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{ self.alpha = 0.0; } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [self.displayLink invalidate];
    }];
}

- (void)rotate
{
    // ....
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call `-beginAnimation` before the completion block in `-endAnimation` has run -- that is, before the 0.5 second animation has finished -- you will overwrite the old `self.displayLink` with the new one. Afterwards, when the completion block runs, you will invalidate the new display link, not the old one.

Use an intermediate variable to capture the value of `self.displayLink` that holds the display link that you want to invalidate. Also, for good measure, set `self.displayLink` to nil when you are done with it.

```
- (void)beginAnimation // triggered by a UIButton
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{ self.alpha = 1.0; }];

    if (self.displayLink != nil) {
        // You called -beginAnimation before you called -endAnimation.
        // I'm not sure if your code is doing this or not, but if it does,
        // you need to decide how to handle it.
    } else {
        // Make a new display link.
        self.displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(rotate)];
        [self.displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    }
}

- (void)endAnimation // triggered by another UIButton
{
    if (self.displayLink == nil) {
        // You called -endAnimation before -beginAnimation.
        // Again, you need to determine what, if anything,
        // to do in this case.
    } else {
        CADisplayLink oldDisplayLink = self.displayLink;
        self.displayLink = nil;

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{ self.alpha = 0.0; } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [oldDisplayLink invalidate];
        }];
    }
}
```